# css list display-inline - where the margin comes from?

Tags: css

The below code produces output consisting of two green items. Between those items there is little white space (or whatever the background color is set to). Where does the white space come from and how to get rid of it? I would expect that the output was something like FirstSecond, but it is First Second, with space between.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #096;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
</ul>
</body>the output
```

Comment: I have no idea, great question! It's not part of the margin or anything, according to the Developer Tools in Google Chrome - it's just *there*. So annoying! Does it display like this in every browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul` and `li` have some default margin and padding on them. You will need to reset this if you want no gap or a smaller/larger gap. I think for FF its 30px if i recall correctly but the amount wil vary from browser to browser.

Comment: I tried the question with a `CSS Reset` and there still is a gap.. :/

Comment: @nick: do you have a space between the elements? if you set them as inline then spaces (`\020`) will be rendered if present in the markup.

Comment: @prodigitalson Thanks!! I had space ("Enter", aka New Line) between list items but I never suspected that this would cause space in the output... Works perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try and float the `li` like so: `ul li { float:left }` ... it appears to remove the spacing. Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/h5WKh/)

Answer (score 1):

add float:left; to the style ul li in will cancel the defaul margin